# How we access Magento module configuration?

Tags: php, magento

I'm new with Magento, and I'd like to put some LDAP congiruations in the /etc/local.xml of a module that I've created, but I just can't find how...

Pretty sure everyone knows it, I can't can't find the proper documentation on the Web

Comment: You don't put your own configuration nodes in local.xml, you put them in your module's config.xml. http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration

Comment: Sorry I meant /etc/config.xml and not /etc/local.xml. But thanks for the article, it helped me find how to get the settings !

Answer (score 0):

Example of how to get specific configuration from a config.xml file:

Settings in [my_module]/etc/config.xml

```
<connexions>
    <ldap>
        <host><![CDATA[LDAP_HOST]]></host>
        <username><![CDATA[USERNAME]]></username>
        <password><![CDATA[PASSWORD]]></password>
        <baseDn><![CDATA[BASE_DN]]></baseDn>
    </ldap>
</connexions>
```

Way to call it:

```
Mage::getConfig()->loadModulesConfiguration( 'config.xml' )
                 ->getNode( 'connexions/ldap')
                 ->asXML()
```